# Javascript w2ui objects - can't get type

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, w2ui

I got list of w2ui object on my page. Structure look like that
[image]

And part of what inside
[image]
I want to get only those, which one is type of 'w2layout'.

I use JQuery each to go through like that

```
jQuery.each(w2ui, 
     function(key, value) {
        console.log(value);
      }
);
```

But I can't get the left part!

I tried `typeof` (returns `object`), and `value.constructor` (returns `object` too), tried use `instanceof w2layout` but without success.

`JSON.stringify(value);` throws error `Converting circular structure to JSON`
So how can I get this?